# LTC1668 - COMP1 & COMP2

Tags: analog, adc

The LTC1668 is a 16-bit, 50Msps differential current output DAC.

The datasheet say that the COMP1 pin and COMP2 pin should be bypassed to VSS (-5V) with 0.1µF.

COMP1 is for Current Source Control Amplifier Compensation, and COMP2 is for Internal Bypass Point...

But in my own PCB, I unintentionally connected both COMP1 and COMP2 to GND with 0.1µF!

Everything is fine in appearance!

Can this lead to an error?

Comment: How can you possibly say it won't?

Answer (score 0):

Date sheet says: -

> The COMP2 pin ties to a node in the output current switching
>   circuitry, and it requires a 0.1 μF bypass capacitor. It should be
>   bypassed to VSS along  with  COMP1.

There is no justification to expect that it will function with optimum performance if this rule is ignored. I'm not saying that there are exceptions but those exceptions are not listed.